# When someone's account is deleted, reputation is updated accordingly, and vote count is not updated everywhere

Tags: bug, up-votes

I tried looking up information about this and couldn't find anything, so I decided to post this.

Basically, if you look over my profile on Personal Finance & Money Stack Exchange, you will notice that I have an answer with a given amount of upvotes, let's say N.

And then, when you look at my profile from another community, on Meta for example, that same answer will appear in Top Network Posts with N+1 votes. It also shows N+1 when I check my Top Answers on the Stack Exchange network profile.

The reason is because, at some point, I had received N+1 upvotes on that answer, and the account of one of them was deleted, as explained by the reputation change. It seemed to have updated everything, except these two places. I think the same would apply for downvotes too, but I don't want to make assumptions.

Is this a known minor bug?

Comment: It is indeed a known bug, that hasn't been fixed as far as I can tell. See the duplicate link for more info! :)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell Ah, thanks. I wasn't able to find it.